# What is the meaning of "Let's hear it for feet!"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "**Let's hear it for feet!**" in the following picture (Source:Feet are Neat!),

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, the meaning of "Let's hear it for Somebody" is defined as "used to say that someone deserves praise, or to ask people to show their approval of someone by clapping".

If so, 
does "Let's hear it for feet!" mean " Feet deserve praise" ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula, "Let's hear it for..." can be used to urge others to show approval or appreciation or praise for people, places and things-- including feet.

"Let's hear it for English Language Learners!"

Comment: If so, does that picture ask us to praise Feet? does "Let's hear it for Feet" mean not "use Feet to clap" but "praise Feet"? We looking at the picture of a baby, it looks like a baby are clapping baby's feet .

Comment: No, it's not saying clap your feet. But usually when someone says, "Let's hear it for..." people respond by cheering and/or clapping their hands-- something like that.

Comment: @user22046 If the baby is clapping his feet, that's just his way of showing his appreciation for his feet. But, when you say, "Let's hear it for..." you aren't necessarily telling people to clap their feet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a fairly literal sense, the artist is urging the reader to give applause, cheers, or vocal praise for....feet.

This is somewhat tongue-in-cheek (not meant in a serious way) as the artist knows that feet do not hear us and will get nothing out of the praise or cheers.  This is a common, light-hearted way for informational texts to introduce a subject which will be shown to be beneficial and likely overlooked.